# DataScroller and Datatable in prime react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, primeng-datatable, primereact

I am very new to React and we are trying to primeReact to implement datatables and datascroller on our UI pages. Though, I was able to successfully implement datatables. Now, I want to add datascroller which is like virtual scroll in a datatable. But, I am not sure how to use it. Can someone provide an example of using datascroller in datatable.

https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/datascroller